# Js : How to Copy/Paste text including hyperlinks from webpage to my html page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Let's suppose that thete is a webpage in internet [www.random-webpage.com](http://www.random-webpage.com) , which contains some textual data and including hidden hyperlinks :

**Example :**

test test test clic **here**

And then , when clicking on the "here" , it opens the hyperlink **[www.myhyperlink.com](http://www.myhyperlink.com)**

My purpose is to be able to COPY that whole text with **ctrl+c** and paste it **ctrl+v** inside my html textarea / input and catch the address of the hyperlink not only the text.

I Am doing it under an Angular app , but is there to handle it with js or angular

**Suggestions ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as described in this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData 
you should use `clipboardData.getData(format)` and the format is `'text/html'` but first you need to bind a listener to **paste** event. 
let see the whole code:

```js
let box = document.getElementById('boxLikeTextarea');
let textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
box.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let html = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
  box.innerHTML = html;
});
textarea.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let html = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
  textarea.innerHTML = html;
});
```

```css
#boxLikeTextarea {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">I am a textarea</textarea>
<div id="boxLikeTextarea" contenteditable>I look like a textarea</div>
```

**Note:** because **Textarea** cant show **link** and just show **text** you should have a div to be like **Textarea** to show link in that

Comment: perfect ; something lacks , is how that link may be cliquable ?

Comment: @firasKoubaa then you should remove `contenteditable` from div. you should choose when the div is clicked is able to edit or behave like normal div as a parent and then open the link. but another solution is that on paste event check the link and make the a clickable with js there